# How to differentiate a many-to-many relationships while designing a database?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have to design a database. And I am finding entities and their relationships. But every relationships seems to have a many-to-many relationships. For instance, in my case:

1) A staff manages client

Here a staff can manage zero or more client. Similarly, a client is managed by one or more client.

2) A client orders to buy a stock

Here a client can order zero, one or more stock to buy and a stock can be ordered by zero, one or more client.

3) A client orders to sell a stock

Here a client can order zero, one or more stock to sell and a stock can be ordered by zero, one or more client to sell.

These are some of the examples of my situation. And I am confused how to separate these relationships. There are other numerous cases like these in my scenario. And I am having difficulty to conceptualize the design.

SO, please enlighten me regarding my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's quite a lot to the system you are developing and presumably there are requirements you haven't mentioned so it isn't really possible to come up with a complete answer. But hopefully some of the following will help you to "conceptualize the design" as you describe it.

1) This is a very common scenario and there's pretty much a standard way of dealing with these many-to-many relationships.

If there are 2 entities A and B with a many-to-many relationship then you would normally introduce an entity C that consists of 2 columns - one a foreign key to the unique id of A and the other a foreign key to the unique id of B. And you would remove the foreign key column in entity A pointing to B and vice versa.

i.e

```
|-----| 
|  A  |  
|-----| 
  \|/
   |
   |
  /|\
|-----| 
|  B  |  
|-----|
```

becomes:

```
|-----| |-----|
|  A  | |  B  |
|-----| |-----|
   |       |
   |       |
   |       |
  /|\     /|\
|-------------|
|      C      |
|-------------|
```

The main challenge is often what to call these new entities! Sometimes they might just be something like a_b_relationship but it's good if can identify more meaningful names.

2) It looks like you need to do a bit more analysis to identify all the actual entities. One way of doing this is to go through your description of the system and identify the nouns - often if there's a noun in the description it's appropriate to have an entity in the entity-relationship diagram.

"Order" jumps out as a noun you overlooked.

Typically for order-processing you would have 2 entities - the order that contains the date, total value, customer etc, and a child orderline which identifies how many of which product have been ordered and individual prices. So in ecommerce a shopping cart would be the order and each item in the shopping cart would be an orderline record.

In your scenario we'd have:

```
|----------|            |-----------|
|  client  |            |  product  |
|----------|            |-----------|
      |                       |
      |                       |
      |                       |
     /|\                     /|\   
|-------------|       /|-------------| 
|    order    |--------|  orderline  |
|-------------|       \|-------------|
```

3) Client sells many products

Here you are identifying an additional role for a client and what I'd do here is question whether "client" is an appropriate entity at this stage. You may find it easier to think in terms of "buyer" and "seller" until the first-cut design is understood. If buyer and seller have a lot in common (especially if an individual can be both a buyer and a seller) then you may decide to use a single entity eventually. Your ERD tool may provide support for this - have a search for "subtype entities" or "entity subtypes".

The specifics will depend on your actual application but it could be that each orderline should have a relationship to the seller, and the order a relationship to the buyer. This will depend on whether it is possible for example for a buyer to order a number of items of a particular product, some of which are sourced from one seller and some from another. It could get complicated!

Also, it might be helpful to consider whether you need to record a seller's stock prior to it being sold. Here it might be useful to distinguish between "product" and "stock", e.g.

```
|---------| |-----------|
|  seller | |  product  |
|---------| |-----------|
   |           |
   |           |
   |           |
  /|\         /|\
|-----------------|
|      stock      |
|-----------------|
```

As a general comment I'd say it really can help to go through the design process step by step. So once you have got your initial model, assign all the data items you need to store to the appropriate entity, and methodically make sure that the design is in first normal form, then second normal form then 3rd normal form. Only once you have done this, and are confident that the design reflects the requirements, should you think about how to implement the design in a database. That's what I learned many years ago anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That's hard to answer this question. Everything in designing is situational. If you really need to store which of staffs manage the client and a client could managed by many staffs, yes your relation is many-to-many. Pay attention there is many relations between entities in real world; you should just store which of them are important and necessary to be stored.

For another example, if your stock contain the available count of that kind of goods, thus the relation between client and stock is many-to-many too.

**Note:** Don't use plural form of noun for you tables' name, it leads you to be confused about relations.

**Edit**: To apply many-to-many relationship in your database tables, you will need a mediator table. For example about Customer and Product table, you should create a table named CustomerProduct (Or everything you want). CustomerProduct table contains two foreign keys, one from Customer table and another from Product table. Usually (not all the time) one many-to-many relationship breakdown to two many-to-one relationships. 
See this [Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/joycsharp/archive/2008/04/21/design-factors-13-how-do-we-generally-handle-one-to.aspx) .

Comment: There is a table of customers who can purchase many different products and a table of products that can be purchased by many different customers. So, how can I break them down as many-to-many relationship is not allowed in database design.

Comment: @user3127109: This is different problem, I've edit my answer. Please read edited section.